# How to git clone a ionic project?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Recently I have to setup my new operating system. My all ionic project uploaded in git. When I clone my project and run  `npm install` it shows some error. My question is how to install all ionic dependencies if I clone my project from git and run properly?

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check if you have all the dependencies listed in your package.json.
2. Run `npm i` or `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

You can install all dependencies and plugins by adding them into **package.json**. If you need help understanding package.json, you can look [here](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/04/20/ionic-adds-a-new-state-feature?utm_content=buffer20073&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) and [here](https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/install-or-reinstall-all-cordova-plugins-in-package-json-with-ionic) to have better understanding. So just make your package.json file and after cloning your project install dependencies.

Or simply try **npm install**